# Born habor Cycles (specifically of MgO)

Tags: bond

So on an exam paper they have said to find out the enthalpy of formation for MgO is : ∆H = 148 + 736 + 1450 + 496/2 - 141 + 798 – 3791
 = –552 kJ mol–1 , however if you draw out the born habor cycle you can see that the second enthalpy of electron affinity for O- is endothermic, so the arrow points up, meaning it should be 148 + 736 + 1450 + 496/2 - 141 -798 -3781

Please explain which is right
Thanks

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of numbers. It would be nice of you to tell us what does each of them mean.

Answer (score 1):

The answer key is correct. You're trying to determine $\Delta H$ for:

$$\ce{Mg(s) + 1/2 O2(g) -> MgO(s)}$$

Since enthalpy is a state function, we can take any path between reactants and products and the *net* change in enthalpy will be the same.

This sequence is deduced from your numbers and the reaction. All units are $\mathrm{kJ\ mol}^{-1}$.

Vaporization energy for magnesium:
$$\ce{Mg(s) + 1/2 O2(g) -> Mg(g) + 1/2 O2(g), \Delta H = +148}$$

First ionization energy for magnesium:
$$\ce{Mg(g) + 1/2 O2(g) -> Mg+(g) + e- + 1/2 O2(g), \Delta H = +736}$$

Second ionization energy for magnesium:
$$\ce{Mg+(g) + e- + 1/2 O2(g) -> Mg^{2+}(g) + 2e- + 1/2 O2(g), \Delta H = +1450}$$

Bond dissociation energy for dioxygen (that's where there's division by 2):
$$\ce{Mg^{2+}(g) + 2e- + 1/2 O2(g) -> Mg^{2+}(g) + 2e- + O(g)}, \Delta H = +\frac{496}{2}$$

First electron affinity of oxygen:
$$\ce{Mg^{2+}(g) + 2e- + O(g) -> Mg^{2+}(g) + e- + O-(g)}, \Delta H = -141$$

Second electron affinity of oxygen. This one is positive:
$$\ce{Mg^{2+}(g) + e- + O-(g) -> Mg^{2+}(g) + O^{2-}(g)}, \Delta H = +798$$

There are two steps left but only 1 number, so I'm not sure what's going on there, unless you're forming magnesium oxide in the gaseous state:
$$\ce{Mg^{2+}(g) + O^{2-}(g) -> MgO(g)}, \Delta H = ?$$
$$\ce{MgO(g) -> MgO(s)}, \Delta H = ?$$

The key point is this: If you take all of the equations I wrote and you add them up and cancel out equivalent species on both sides, you get the original equation at the top which is the reaction for formation of magnesium oxide. The change in enthalpy is the simple the sum of all the deltas for the components of the cycle. The contribution from the second electron affinity is therefore positive.

It's really easy to get the signs mixed up if you're just focusing on the procedure instead of thinking about what the sign means. Here the positive sign means that energy must be put into the system to achieve the reaction, hence endothermic.